How can I listen for long-press event on an image in webview_flutter
I'm using webview_flutter package to show webview on my app, I want to listen for long-press events on any image within a WebView and retrieve the URL of that image. I don't known how to do that.
This video describes what I want to achieve
Can someone suggest a solution for me? Thank all.

I think you need to wrap your webview inside a GestureDetector, and you can include an onLongPress as a parameter.

i don't think this can be done, however you can use JavaScript and perform DOM tasks,
